# Automate storing of Outlook emails (not just attachments) to SharePoint Online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, email, outlook, flow

I have a SharePoint Online environment and am trying to automate the process of storing Outlook emails with a particular subject or emails in an Outlook folder to SharePoint Doc Lib.

I am trying to save the whole email to the document library, not just attachments of that email.

I have found multiple MS Flow templates that store attachments of Outlook emails to a document library but hasn't found any template that actually saves the whole email to a document library.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible, though the action is in preview. The action is "export email", and is an action, not a trigger. So first have a trigger based on receiving an email, then "export email", then a sharepoint create file action, which can use the "body" property of the export action for the file content. (the body property is the email, not just the body of the email).

For more details, see the announcement [here](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/outlook-connector-more/).

Comment: Awesome, That worked like a charm. The only problem is i am trying to save file in .msg format. And it throws an error saying "We can't open .msg. It's possible the file is already open or you don't permissions to access this file." Any suggestions to resolve this? I have tried it in .eml/.pdf formats as well. Both formats are not displaying any data.

Comment: The documentation is ... thin, but it seems it only supports eml format. I've tested the eml, and it's working fine for me.